# How to give input in cmd commands from Java

Tags: java, mysql, cmd

I am new to this console problems. I am simply creating a application which executes few command lines. I have a commands

```
mysql -u root -p
```

which is for opening MySQL console.
Here, how can I input password?
I did:-

```
cd c:\\Program Files (x86)\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin
   && mysql -u root -p && root && create database testingdb; 
   && quit && mysql –u root –p testingdb < mysql_dump.testingdb.sql
```

Here, first input is root which is password and second `mysql_dump.testingdb.sql` is sql file located in `mysql_dump` package.
This is not working and a thread is opened even though cmd console window is close.

How does java work in this situation?

Comment: You might be better using JDBC? Have you considered it? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 0):

you can use Runtime class to execute OS commands. Since i donot have mysql installed canot check the senario mentioned. checked with cmd commands.

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec("mysql -u root -p");  
    InputStream is = pr.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(inputLine); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Running the command

[ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) provides a full API for starting commands.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("mysql", "-u", "root", "-p");
processBuilder.directory(new File("myDir"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

### Pipe into the command

You can write strings into a BufferedWriter that wraps the confusingly named "output" stream from the Process object returned by processBuilder.start()

```
OutputStream stdin = proc.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(stdin);
BuffererWriter bw = new BuffererWriter(osr);
bw.write("Hello\n");
```

### A word of warning

You need to be very careful when using Process to consume the standard output/error streams otherwise the process can lock. A robust implementation should create 2 threads to read stdout and stderr asynchronously and perhaps a 3rd to feed the process.

> The parent process uses these streams (#getInputStream(),
>   getErrorStream()) to feed input to and get output from the subprocess. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer
>   size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write
>   the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause
>   the subprocess to block, and even deadlock.

This guide [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) has all the information you need.